# Set ajax-fetched data to component before render

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router with file based components. I called one of the routes `CaseDetail.vue` and it gets a parameter (slug) which fetches a json from an API with axios.

I'm doing this with ”[In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)”, with the method called `beforeRouteEnter`. I'm passing the response from axios into the next-method.

```
    axios.get('/case/'+ to.params.slug +'.json').then((response) => {
      next(vm => {
        vm.entry = response.data;
      })
    });
```

Which works, but, Vue renders the view before the data gets set. Which generates `undefined` errors. How can I tell Vue to wait for it to get the data?

My template:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
  </main>
</template>
```

My component:

```
export default{

 name: 'CaseDetail',
 data(){
    return{         
        entry: null
    };
 },

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing steps:

1. axios api is calling
2. component is created
3. next() in `beforeRouteEnter` is called. At that time, because component is created, so `vm` variable is available.

If you console log in your component

```
  created() {
    console.log('Component is created!')
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      next(vm => {
        console.log('next() is called')
      })
    }, 3000)
  },
```

Then the result will be

> Component is created!
>
> next() is called

You should set default value to your data, or add a safety check.

```
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>{{ entry? entry.title: '' }}</h1>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting default values makes sense, however, I was hoping there was a way to prevent creation of the component before it had the required data. I would like to have as little logic as possible in the templates. Is it possible pass the GET-data into the `beforeCreate` method, or something similar?

Comment: Normally I will call api in `created` hook of components. In the mean time, I can show a loading state to user. I think this will bring better user experience. 
If you want to use `beforeCreate `, when user click on a link, if internet connection or api response is slow, user will feel website is hanging (not good user experience)

Comment: I agree that is better ux, I was looking on an example like that [here in the vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html). There's however no explanation what (seems to be in the global namespace)  `getPost`-method they're using in the example works.